# How do I use a Google Font with NODE.js server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, google-font-api

I am developing an app that is using NODE.js and REACT. I am trying to load a Google Font. (Open Sans) And I am not sure the best way to do that?

1) Do I need to install and npm module for Google Fonts?
2) Do I need to integrate it with Webpack? 
3) Can I just use the standard  tag? If so where should it go?

Any info on the best way to do this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you have your web pages just load the Google fonts straight from a Google CDN?  I'm unsure why your node.js server needs to be involved at all.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right.  you would load the css Google gives you in your index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the Google font URLs directly into your web pages and your node.js server doesn't need to do anything specific.   There's an example shown here: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks everyone. I just wasn't sure if I had to do anything special. It originally wasn't working, but I figured out that was due to a typo in the font declaration in the CSS. Now everything is working as normal. Thanks for your clarification.